# Unable to lock and unlock screen orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibm-mobilefirst, device-orientation

I'm struggling to modify the device orientation. I found this cordova plugin  https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation and it's working with cordova app but unfortunately is not working using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 (+Angular, Ionic).

I unlocked the device orientation in Xcode -> general:
[image: xcode my project general]

I also tried to do small twist to the screen orientation cordova plugin according this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6165 but it still not working

this is the interface it look the YoikScreenOrientation.h

```
@interface ForcedViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *calledWith;

@end
```

and YoikScreenOrientation.m

```
@implementation ForcedViewController

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
        NSLog(@"lockViewController to ALL Portrait < 9");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    }
#else
    -(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
        NSLog(@"lockViewController to ALL Portrait > 9");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
#endif

@end
```

I can see in the logs that it passes through the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method but it does not lock the screen orientation to portrait. Is there any configuration that I missed in order to lock or unlock the device orientation?

Comment: 1) What is the end goal? Are you attempting to accomplish locking and unlocking programmatically instead of the Device orientation option in the General options? 2) What does Angular and Ionic have to do with the question? 3) Are you testing in a physical device or in the iOS Simulator?

Comment: 1)The goal is locking the screen orientation in one page and then unlocking  it again, I added the images where the general option is unlocked to pointing out that the device orientation is unlocked. 2) nothing really just it's the  framework that I'm using to build the app, 3) yes I tested in both simulator and real device and it's the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Well definitely Cordova  plugin screen orientation does not help in this case, so I ended up creating my our plugin using  this example http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-orientations-landscape-orientation-one-view-controller/ and that works, the key to change the orientation is this function which is called before the orientation is changed, that way I could override the orientation to Landscape or Portrait mode,
appdelegate.m

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
    {
        if ([LANSCAPE_MODE isEqualToString:orientationMode]){
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
            else
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

        }
        else{
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
        }

    }
```

If I trying to override using supportedInterfaceOrientations method it crash if the orientation is not supported, this link explains the crash 
https://devforums.apple.com/message/731764#731764

Comment: Any change you can give a bit more information on that plugin you made yourself? I'm struggling with the same issue.